# PySide2 with Built-In Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pyside2

I try to modify the original code written in PyQt5 to [PySide2](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python) as the license problems. In the original code (PyQt5), I use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) in QThread to increase CPU usage, and it works perfectly. However, after modified to PySide2, the code generates a series of error and destroy the GUI. The following is a minimized example to cause the problem.

The following code works well when I use PyQt5 instead of PySide2.

```py
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

class Task(QThread):
    def run(self):
        print('task started')
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            res = pool.map(mp_task, range(10000))
        print('task finished', res)

def mp_task(x):
    # some heavy tasks
    ret = 0
    for i in range(x + 50000):
        ret += i
    return ret

class Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton('click me')
        button.clicked.connect(self.do_task)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def do_task(self):
        self.thread = Task()
        self.thread.start()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Gui()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**However**, if I change the import package from `PyQt5` to `PySide2`, for example,

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
```

after clicking the button, the GUI will be destroyed and the program generates the following error messages (some repeated messages has been omitted):

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x1cb19c0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1948cc0), current thread is Task(0x7fc1d0005390)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x1cb19c0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1948cc0), current thread is Task(0x7fc1d0005390)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x1cb19c0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1948cc0), current thread is Task(0x7fc1d0005390)
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 128 (Unknown), sequence: 548, resource id: 88080397, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 2
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 128 (Unknown), sequence: 552, resource id: 88080397, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 2
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x1cb19c0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1948cc0), current thread is Task(0x7fc1d0005390)
```

Maybe there are some differences between PyQt5 and PySide2 in QThread and lead to this fatal error. If I do not want to move `QApplication` and `Gui` into global scope, how could I fix the problem?

Testing environment: Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit, Python3.6, PyQt5 5.11.2, PySide2 5.11.1

Comment: PySide2 and PyQT are internally different. Since you found a solution to your question, you can add it as an answer. I'm sure this will help many other users.

Comment: @NicholasTJ, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if I put the contents of the `main()` function to global scope, the problem solved! For example:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Gui()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Furthermore, Qt6 will soon be released with multiple Python integration improvements. This problem might be solved with the new version of PySide.